# Using wkhtmltopdf with Bootstrap 3 removes color styles

Tags: css, colors, twitter-bootstrap-3, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to create pdf reports from Meteor, using the SSR package and wkhtmltopdf. Things are going well, except for one thing: when I link bootstrap 3, I lose all colors. The column format, table format, etc is all fine, but everything is white on black. Even if I use inline css, all I get is black on white.

If I remove the boostrap link, all the colors come through as expected.

Here's the template I'm rendering:

```
<Template name="spaceUtilSpacePDF">
    <html>
        <head> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="well">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="bg-danger"> Stuff</td>
                                    <td style="background-color:blue"> Stuff</td>
                                    <td style="color:red"> Stuff</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                   </div>
            </div>
            <div style="page-break-after:always"></div>
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Test Button</button>

        </body>
    </html>

</Template>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is probably because of [the following snippet from the HTML5 Boilerplate that's included in Bootstrap v3:](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/3efa9c46a40e49109e7a14d58ee7f8b170a3d17b/less/print.less#L13)

```
/*! Source: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/css/main.css */
// ==========================================================================
// Print styles.

@media print {
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #000 !important; // Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s
    //...
  }
```

You can either remove this from your copy of Bootstrap, or try to override it.

Note that Bootstrap v4 has removed this snippet.

Comment: @crush Download the less / sass file and configure yourself?

Comment: Great tip. I was able to get the color to show up simply by adding `!important` to my color rule.